Enabling A2DP source and disabling A2DP sink in Ubuntu 22.04
Please help, I am pretty new to Bluetooth in Ubuntu.
I am using BlueZ 5.64 running on Ubuntu 22.04.
Does anyone know if it is possible for me to enable only A2DP source, since my device should be able to stream music to a Bluetooth earpiece? If possible, how? Similarly it should not be treated as some sort of audio output device and so A2DP sink should be disabled.
Can this be done in bluetoothctl?
I've tried to lookup ways to disable particular Bluetooth services and it seems to be possible for my device running Ubuntu 22.04 to disable the A2DP completely (both source and sink) by changing this line in /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service:
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --noplugin=a2dp
Thanks in advance!
